# class SwipeGestureDetector not working in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gridview, swipe

I have created android app using gridlist and swipe for images like gallery or small book which have 10 images

grid list and image view got open successfully and i am able to launch the application.

Functionality is also working fine but when I want to swipe next image from grid-list  then my app close and showing message that app has stopped and open app again.

Please review my code and guide me how can I solve this problem.
Here is my code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private GridView gv;
    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;
    private int j = 0;

    private GestureDetector detector;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    private int thumb[] = { R.drawable.img_android, R.drawable.img_chrome,
            R.drawable.img_facebook, R.drawable.img_firefox,
            R.drawable.img_gmail, R.drawable.img_google_plus,
            R.drawable.img_java, R.drawable.img_linux, R.drawable.img_skype,
            R.drawable.img_twitter, R.drawable.img_windows,
            R.drawable.img_wordpress };

    private ImageView expandedImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        detector = new GestureDetector(this, new SwipeGestureDetector());

        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                    long id) {
                j = pos;
                zoomImageFromThumb(v, thumb[pos]);
            }
        });

        mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
    }

    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public ImageAdapter(MainActivity activity) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return thumb.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View listItem = convertView;
            int p = pos;

            if(listItem == null) {
                listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_grid_item, null);
            }

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.thumb);

            iv.setBackgroundResource(thumb[p]);

            return listItem;
        }
    }

    private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {

        if(mCurrentAnimator != null) {
            mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
        }

        expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);

        expandedImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(detector.onTouchEvent(event)){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);

        final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
        final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
        final Point globalOffset = new Point();

        thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
        findViewById(R.id.container).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);

        startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
        finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

        float startScale;

        if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() > (float) startBounds
                .width() / startBounds.height()) {

            startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
            float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
            float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
            startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
            startBounds.right += deltaWidth;

        } else {

            startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
            float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
            float deltaHeight = (startHeight = startBounds.height()) / 2;
            startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
            startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
        }

        thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
        expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();

        set.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale, 1f))
        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));

        set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
        set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }
        });
        set.start();
        mCurrentAnimator = set;

        final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
        expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                    mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
                }

                AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();

                set.play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));

                set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
                set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }
                });
                set.start();
                mCurrentAnimator = set;
            }
        });
    }

    private class SwipeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {

            try {

                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){

                    if(thumb.length > j) {
                        j++;

                        if(j < thumb.length) {
                            expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            j = 0;
                            expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                } else if(e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                    if(j > 0) {
                        j--;
                        expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        j = thumb.length - 1;
                        expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use ViewPager For Swipeable views.

Comment: can you show me code like as you saying sorry because am new in andriod

Comment: go check my answer and do comment if any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use View Pager For Swipeable Views/fragment.

Write this Code in your layout file `activity_main.xml`.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Next, in your `onCreate()` Activity method, you’ll instantiate your custom PagerAdapter implementation and bind it to your ViewPager object something like this.

```
 CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);

   ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
```

After that create a layout file(`pager_item.xml`) which will be inflated on `ViewPager` at a time and will contain your `ImageView` Something Like This.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now create a new class  `CustomPagerAdapter.java`and write your custom pager adapter implementation that’ll do the real job of populating content pages within our ViewPager.

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

   private int mResources[] = { R.drawable.img_android, R.drawable.img_chrome,
        R.drawable.img_facebook, R.drawable.img_firefox,
        R.drawable.img_gmail, R.drawable.img_google_plus,
        R.drawable.img_java, R.drawable.img_linux, R.drawable.img_skype,
        R.drawable.img_twitter, R.drawable.img_windows,
        R.drawable.img_wordpress };


    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help here is error showing : error: cannot find symbol variable mCustomPagerAdapter 
error: cannot find symbol variable mViewPager 
error: cannot find symbol variable mCustomPagerAdapter 
error: cannot find symbol variable mViewPager

Comment: Hello Thanks for help its working now but i need help that 1st all image show in main activity as gridview after that click anyone image then will move all image like ViewPager

Comment: You mean you want to make it like the gallery.

Comment: And please tick this as right if it helped you  for your query.

Comment: yeah you can say like gallery. i post my all code which work like as grideview and open one image but next not work like as pager

Comment: I solved what you have asked in this question, and the next question should be asked on another thread. so sir please ask it as another question. And Sir please tick this answer as you said it worked for you.

Comment: Where is tick option. and please if you understand what am want then please help me using your code

Comment: Here is new thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889613/want-to-create-simple-app-like-the-gallery-i-have-coded-but-class-swipegesturede

Comment: it's not how StackOverflow works but still, I have added another answer for different query go check it and do comment if any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's another answer for your another query

You have to create two activities one with `GridView`(which you had completed) and another with `ViewPager`(which you can create with the help of my first answer).

Now you want to show `ViewPager` on click of `GridView` here's how you can do it:-

```
 gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                    long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewPagerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position",pos);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

And now the `ViewPagerActivity.java`:-

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class ViewPagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);

         Intent mIntent = getIntent();
         int position= mIntent.getIntExtra("position", 0);

         ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
         mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
         mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

    }
}
```

Comment: yeah you are right i have two activities one with GridView and 2nd want to show ViewPager on click of GridView..am confuse because want to know have you code this according my code which i post in question ?

Comment: i have try your new code and create new ViewPagerACtivity so next showing this issue see in screenshot :- http://prntscr.com/jw2x2y

Comment: copy and paste the code of ViewPagerActivity again.

Comment: still getting error so i have change my all code and create new thread please check and help me there.. can we contact on email.i want to send you my all code. here is my new thread : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906577/getting-error-in-setgridviewitemclicklistener