# Getting error in setGridViewItemClickListener and also how can show images from drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have created android app using `GridView` with `ViewPager` for images like gallery or small book which have 14 images
am showing all image from URL. i want also help that how can show my image from drawable

`GridView` got open successfully and i am able to launch the application.

Functionality is also working fine but when I want to open single image from `GridView` then my app close and showing message that app has stopped and open app again.

Please review my code and guide me how can I solve this problem. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> listImageURLs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addImageURLs();

        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, listImageURLs);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);






        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        setGridViewItemClickListener();
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void setGridViewItemClickListener(){
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("position", position);
            bundle.putStringArrayList("imageURLs", listImageURLs);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }

    private void addImageURLs(){
        listImageURLs.add("http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/04/12/23/3319F89C00000578-3536787-image-m-19_1460498410943.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("https://www.w3schools.com/css/pineapple.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("https://www.w3schools.com/css/lights600x400.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-11.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-15.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-19.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/thumb700x/heic1509a.jpg");
        listImageURLs.add("http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-12.jpg");
        //listImageURLs.addAll(listImageURLs);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your logcat also

Comment: open logcat window and copy the error part and paste here please

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: Context not passed correctly. Check my answer.

Comment: Process: com.ukhyips.httpwww.specialmehndidesigns, PID: 15308
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ukhyips.httpwww.specialmehndidesigns/com.ukhyips.httpwww.specialmehndidesigns.ImageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the ImageActivity in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: Thanks its working now when i added ImageActivity in the AndroidManifest..need some more information. am getting all image from URL..can you help me how can upload image in my drawable and show from there

Comment: Hi, for me, the best way to show images from URL is using Picasso Picasso.get().load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2); 
http://square.github.io/picasso/ you need include INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `OnItemClickListener` in the place of context. You need to use the instance of the class like below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
```

*Note:* If you use `this`, then it would have the instance of the class it is written in. In your code, you are using `this` inside an anonymous class of `OnItemClickListener`

Also, you need to check if you have defined your activity in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar project with you and I use this way:

`private ArrayList<String> urlImage = new ArrayList<>();`

Remember, add data to `urlImage`

`gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShowImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(KEY_URL_IMAGE, urlImage);
                intent.putExtra(KEY_POSITION, String.valueOf(position));
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });`

In ShowImageActivity:

`Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            url = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getExtras().get(KEY_URL_IMAGE);
            position = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(intent.getExtras().get(KEY_POSITION)));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL image" + url.get(position) + "position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }`

`final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), url));
        final ViewPager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewPager.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = ViewPager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layoutParams.height = ViewPager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`

and show image from drawable

`imageView.setImageResource(getImageId(view.getContext(),resourceImage));`

`public static int getImageId(Context context, String imageName) {
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName, null, context.getPackageName());
    }`